# Any way to know if the click is coming from a "trigger" or actual click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a curious situation. I am editing a page that is a gazzilion moving parts.

Anyways, I have a dialog box (popup) that is bound (via the dialog creation class) to a body click handler. Basically, if you click anywhere on the page, it closes. Ok, great.

Here is the rub. There is another process on the page that runs that "$(body).trigger('click')". This is creating an issue, because in THIS situation, I do not want my particular dialog to close.

I ran some tests and they appear to be identical --
1.) generating a click via a trigger
2.) and actually clicking on the body of the page.

Is there any discernible way to know if a click is a "fake" trigger call or real 'click' event? Since nothing is bubbling in a triggered click, is there anyways to somehow try to see if there is a child elem on the page to see if its bubbling or something?

I hope I am succinct enough in my explanation.

Comment: Faked triggers rarely have mouse coordinates in their event, try it.

Comment: can you check the event object passed to the event handler?

Comment: If you don't want to check the event object, you could just make a handoff function passing an extra parameter or two detailing the origin of the event.

Comment: @Night - yeah, I don't want to go that route as I want to minimize my imprint on the current code as much as possible. Thanks though. Wait - BUT I can check the event object. I looked thru it, what is there that would be of use?

Comment: @gp - yes, I don't see why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="click me" />
```

JS:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(e) {
    if(typeof e.isTrigger == 'undefined') {
        console.log("clicked");
    } else {
        console.log("triggered");
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#button").trigger("click");
}, 1000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wXnwp/1/

A version for jQuery 1.6 => http://jsfiddle.net/wXnwp/3/

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    if(typeof e.ctrlKey !== 'undefined') {
        console.log("clicked");
    } else {
        console.log("triggered");
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#button").trigger("click");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: great thank you ! I didn't realize that there is a "isTrigger" -- dang, I just looked. I am not using jquery 1.7 - that looks to be used in that revision. I only have 1.6. arrghh. this is what i needed too!!! hmm. Maybe I can use a polyfil to do it.. I upvoted just cause its a good answer. But it won't work for me. clever though.

Comment: Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wXnwp/3/ Open the console and click the button. You will see that the both objects has a lot of differences. This fiddle also works with 1.6

Comment: That worked too! Great. Thanks. Curious -- why go with ctrlKey? I see that currentTarget or originalEvent might be good alternatives too. Just curious what ctrlKey specifies. (I thought it was just controlkey).

Comment: No reason actually. Feel free to use whatever you think is right.